# How to place parameter from a widget into an entry level call in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to implemment the audio_service on my application. The documentation last that _backgroundTaskEntrypoint() must be a entry level function. The problem is: I need to send parameters received by the widget to this class. I don't know how to do that. It's more easy to show the code for a better understanding, but basically, I can't do simething like : sound: widget.sound, cover: widget.cover or MediaPlayer().sound and MediaPlayer.image.

Any clue ?

```
class MediaPlayer extends StatefulWidget {
  final String sound;
  final String cover;
  MediaPlayer({Key? key, required this.sound, required this.cover})
      : super(key: key);
  @override
  _MediaPlayerState createState() => _MediaPlayerState();
}

class _MediaPlayerState extends State<MediaPlayer> {
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    play();
    return StreamBuilder<PlaybackState>( ... )
}

// The issue is on the line bellow:
_backgroundTaskEntrypoint() {
  AudioServiceBackground.run(() => AudioPlayerTask(sound: sound parameter from widget here, cover: cover parameter from widget here));
}

class AudioPlayerTask extends BackgroundAudioTask {
  final _audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
  final String sound;
  final String cover;
  AudioPlayerTask(
    {required this.sound, required this.cover})
  @override
  Future<void> onStart(Map<String, dynamic>? params) async {
    print('Starting...');
    AudioServiceBackground.setState(
        controls: [MediaControl.pause, MediaControl.stop],
        systemActions: [MediaAction.seekTo],
        playing: true,
        position: _audioPlayer.position,
        processingState: AudioProcessingState.connecting);
    await _audioPlayer.setAsset(sound);
    AudioServiceBackground.setMediaItem(new MediaItem(
        id: '600',
        title: 'the title',
        album: 'the album',
        duration: _audioPlayer.duration,
        artUri: Uri.parse(cover)));
    _audioPlayer.play();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_backgroundTaskEntrypoint` will be run in a background isolate, so you won't be able to access any widgets from that method.  Fortunately, `AudioService.start` accepts a `params` object, which can be used to provide parameters to `BackgroundAudioTask.onStart`.

```dart
// wherever you already have this method call
AudioService.start(
  backgroundTaskEntrypoint: _backgroundTaskEntrypoint,
  params: {
    'sound': widget.sound,
    'cover': widget.cover,
  },
  // ... any other parameters
)

void _backgroundTaskEntryPoint() {
  AudioServiceBackground.run(() => AudioPlayerTask());
}

class AudioPlayerTask extends BackgroundAudioTask {
  final _audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();

  @override
  Future<void> onStart(Map<String, dynamic>? params) async {
    final sound = params!['sound'] as String;
    final cover = params!['cover'] as String;
    print('Starting...');
    AudioServiceBackground.setState(
        controls: [MediaControl.pause, MediaControl.stop],
        systemActions: [MediaAction.seekTo],
        playing: true,
        position: _audioPlayer.position,
        processingState: AudioProcessingState.connecting);
    await _audioPlayer.setAsset(sound);
    AudioServiceBackground.setMediaItem(new MediaItem(
        id: '600',
        title: 'the title',
        album: 'the album',
        duration: _audioPlayer.duration,
        artUri: Uri.parse(cover)));
    _audioPlayer.play();
```

Comment: Man...you deserve a beer...not one, two..but a lot of beers ! ty !

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you call this `_backgroundTaskEntryPoint` function, but couldn't you have it accept both `sound` and `cover` as arguments? I would try something like this.

```
_backgroundTaskEntrypoint(String sound, String cover) {
  AudioServiceBackground.run(() => AudioPlayerTask(sound: sound, cover: cover));
}
```

And initialize it in the `MediaPlayer` `initState`

```
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _backgroundTaskEntryPoint(widget.sound, widget.cover);
}
```

Comment: yes..this looks natural...was some of my attempts....but...Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Function'